# Drush makefile downloading 7.x Dev instead of stable

Tags: drush

I have drush makefile that I use to kick off new Drupal installs:

**my_profile.build**

```
core = "7.x"
api = "2"

projects[drupal][version] = "7.x"
; ... grab install profile
```

When I run `drush make my_profile.build` it downloads the 7.x-dev version of core instead of stable. I knew that I code force the download of dev versions with `projects[drupal][version] = "7.x-dev"` but how do I make sure that it only downloads the *stable* version of a project? My drush version is 5.7.

Comment: Use projects[] = drupal this will download the latest stable version of drupal as long as you specify the core version using core = "7.x"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To always specify the latest major version of Drupal, just use

```
projects[drupal][version] = 7
```

For modules and themes, just omit the version. For example:

```
projects[views][type] = module
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the exact version in the makefile:

```
projects[drupal][type] = core
projects[drupal][version] = "7.23"
```

Since it's auto selecting `-dev` (which isn't the default `stable` is) it sounds like your `drush.rc` file is tweaked to make `-dev` a default option ...